# Heap corruption upon using delete[] on an array

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

This is my code:

```
int* mergeArrays(int* a, int m, int* b, int n)
{
    int *c;
    c = new int(m + n);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m + n; i++)
        c[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];
    cout << i;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        c[i] = b[j];
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m + n - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < m + n; j++)
            if (c[i] > c[j])
                swap(c[i], c[j]);
    return c;
}
```

Error appear when I use `delete[]a` in `main()`
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Aside: is this meant to be part of a `mergeSort`, where `a` and `b` point to sorted arrays? There should be one pass over the input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = new int(m + n);
```

This allocates a pointer to **one** `int`, and initialize its value to `m + n`.

What you want is:

```
c = new int[m + n];
```